# Sharpnado.Tabs Using to design this Screenshort Ui in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:tabs="clr-namespace:Sharpnado.Tabs;assembly=Sharpnado.Tabs"
            xmlns:sh="clr-namespace:Sharpnado.Shades;assembly=Sharpnado.Shadows"
             x:Class="SplashTest.Segment">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                            SelectedIndex="1"
                           
                              
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Animate="True"
                              >
            </tabs:ViewSwitcher>
      
            <tabs:TabHostView x:Name="TabHost"
                    Grid.Row="4"
                    HeightRequest="54"
                      
                    Margin="20,15,20,0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                               Padding="60,0,60,0"
                    BackgroundColor="#F0F0F3"
                    Shades="{sh:SingleShade Offset='0,8',
                                            BlurRadius=10,
                                            Color=Gray
                                           }"
                    CornerRadius="100"
                              
                             
                    IsSegmented="True"
                    SegmentedHasSeparator="False"
                  
                    TabType="Fixed"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
           
            <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs >
              
                <tabs:SegmentedTabItem Style="{StaticResource SegmentedTabStyle}"   Label="Male" />
                <tabs:SegmentedTabItem Style="{StaticResource SegmentedTabStyle}" Label="Female" />
            </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
               
        </tabs:TabHostView>
          
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

> Above Xaml The Male Tab is corner radius working only left side not in
> the Right side how to i give corner radius in both left and right side
> in xamrin forms .Note I have install Sharpnado plugin and intilizing
> in App.Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Frame` and apply corner radius for all corners by making custom rendererfor the same. Overlap those two frames based on the selection type.

Refer:[Customizing Frame corner radius with Xamarin.Forms](https://progrunning.net/customizing-corner-radius/)
[Overlap elements in Xamarin.Forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/170283/overlapping-elements-without-using-absolutelayout) [you can use absolute layout as well, if you want]